# Customizing/extending Django Admin Globally

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

I would like to customize "Django administration" text and other features globally. So I followed instruction and added /templates to TEMPLATE_DIRS. The problem is that if I put /templates/admin folder in an app folder then it works, if I put /templates/admin folder in the main project folder it doesn't work. I cannot understand why.

I would like to change "Django administration" text globally and not locally, is it possibile?

File system:

```
main_folder
    - project_folder
    - app1_folder
```

Settings:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/project_folder/templates', #I would like to put globally admin folder here
    '/app1_folder/templates',

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    # 'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

Comment: What is the value of your [`TEMPLATE_LOADERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_LOADERS) setting?

Comment: `TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    # 'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
) `